# tempdata value not getting through ajax call on controller on checkbox event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax, jquery-ajaxq

i want to send parameter to my controller.this is my view page:

```
<div>
  <li> <input name="chk" type="checkbox" value="1"> electronics </li>
  <li> <input name="chk" type="checkbox" value="2"> Construction</li>
  <li> <input name="chk" type="checkbox" value="1"> Hardware</li>
    <div class="row service-block" id="results">
      @Html.Partial("_searchPartial", Model)
    </div>
</div>


 $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('chk');
            var vals = "";
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    vals += "," + checkboxes[i].value;
                }
            }
            if (vals) vals = vals.substring(1);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Search/SearchWorkers",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { checkCategoriesId: vals,"City": "@ViewBag.City", "OrderBy": "@TempData["OrderBy"]" },
                contentType: "text/html;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (responce)
                {
                    $("#results").html(responce);
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert("test");
                }
            })
        });
```

This is my controller:
 first of all i am calling this method where i am preserving orderby value.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SearchPaging(string ItemSearchText,string City, string OrderBy, int PageNo, string Zipcode, string Flag,string checkCategoriesId)
        {
            TempData["OrderBy"] = OrderBy;
            return PartialView("_searchPartial", userDetailsModel.OrderBy(v => v.Fullname).ToPagedList(PageNo, 1));
    }




[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchWorkers(string checkCategoriesId,string OrderBy,string Flag,string City, int PageNo = 1)
{ 
 TempData["OrderBy"] = OrderBy
  return PartialView("_searchPartial", userDetailsModel.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedDate).ToPagedList(PageNo, 1));
}
```

i have checked tempdata value and it is showing value on view page.

but when i am firing checkbox change event and i am passing tempdata value then i am getting null value.

i dont know whats the problem

can anybody figure out?

Comment: Both you action methods set `TempData["OrderBy"] = OrderBy;` where `OrderBy` is a parameter passed to the method. Where and how do you first call the `SearchPaging()` method and pass it a value for `OrderBy`?

Comment: $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function (e) {}.through this function i am calling the search paging fucntion and setting the orderby value.

Comment: But does it actually have a value at this point? In the first line of that function, add `console.log('@TempData["OrderBy"]'); and check

Comment: if you are talking about searchpaging function then yes it does have value at that point

Comment: `@TempData["OrderBy"]` is only ever going to evaluated once when you first load the page (its not dynamically updated just because you return a partial view and it contains a different value). I suggest you put the value into a hidden input in the partial and retrieve it in the script.

Comment: as i am returning partial view with ajax.what if i return jsonresult.whose performance will be better and what approach u suggest?

Comment: Returning json will probably give a small improvement (less payload) but then you will have to manually construct the html so could be a lot of extra code. I cant really assess whats best or easiest in your case.

Comment: so where do i preserve this sortby order?

Comment: Include a hidden input in your partial `<input type= "hidden" id="orderby" value="@ViewBag.OrderBy" />` then in your methods assign the value `ViewBag.OrderBy = OrderBy;` and in you script get it with `var orderby = $('#orderby").val();`. But I really don't understand why you need this. Your never changing its value (in effect its a constant) so why do you keep passing it around?

Comment: no orderby value will change because i am having 5 sort by order and based on selection among this 5 sortby order i am storing value in orderby viewbag

Comment: Now it sounds as if the value is set based on a dropdown or something in your view. Why not just declare a variable `var orderby = null;` and then update it when you select a value (and forget all the `ViewBag` stuff). Hard to tell because you haven't posted the relevant code.

Comment: you are right and you are super genius.i cant event thank you because thank you would be so small to tell you

Comment: sir is there any way that i can show you my live working code like what i have done and you can see my code and give me some suggestion?

Comment: your hidden field idea worked.thank you so much......

Answer (score 1):

Although you may have find your answer ,but for others having same question i am adding my answer.

As Stephen Muecke suggested you can use a hidden value to update your value based on checbox changed event.

You can also get the current value of checkbox and pass to controller,
You just need this one line

```
OrderBy: $(this).attr("value");
```

Here is your code:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function ()
{
 $.ajax({
                url: "/Search/SearchWorkers",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { checkCategoriesId: vals,"City": "@ViewBag.City",                   "OrderBy": $(this).attr("value"); },
                contentType: "text/html;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (responce)
                {
                    $("#results").html(responce);
                }
 });
 });
```